# Using multiple checkboxes for same property to filter data in MVC .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, checkbox

I am following the ASP.NET MVC 5 tutorial at http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/getting-started

This tutorial creates a basic database containing movie objects, of which the properties are title, release date, genre, and price.

I have two checkboxes, one for movies who's price is 5, and one for 10.

What I have works fine if only one of the checkboxes is selected, but if both are selected (I am trying to list movies who's price is 5 and movies who's price is 10) then nothing is shown in the view.

Am I way off?

Model:

```
 public class Movie
 {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
    public string Genre { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

 }

public class MovieDBContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
 public class MoviesController : Controller
{
    private MovieDBContext db = new MovieDBContext();



    public ActionResult Index(bool movieCost5 = false, bool movieCost10 = false)
    {

        var movies = from m in db.Movies
                     select m;



        if (movieCost5 == true && movieCost10 == false)
        {
            movies = movies.Where(x => x.Price == 5);
        }
        else if (movieCost5 == true && movieCost10 == true)
        {
            movies = movies.Where(x => x.Price == 5 && x.Price == 10);
        }

        else if (movieCost5 == false && movieCost10 == true)
        {
            movies = movies.Where(x => x.Price == 10);
        }

        return View(movies);
    }
}
```

Comment: In addition to the answer below, you should also cast your `movies` variable as an `IQueryable<Movie>` to delay execution of the database call until you've evaluated your filters. As it is now, the code is saying "Get every movie in the database and store it in memory" then "Get every movie from the in-memory object that matches criteria X". This won't be noticeable on smaller datasets but as they get larger you'll notice your code dragging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
x.Price == 5 && x.Price == 10
```

This means you're looking for movies with price both 5 and 10 at the same time - unless you have some custom logic for comparing your `Price` with integers, this will never work.

You're probably looking for:

```
x.Price == 5 || x.Price == 10
```

(logical OR not logical AND)

**EDIT :**

When working with similar problems it is often useful to try to narrow down your issue, which is something you could have done on your own. If you believed there was some issue with how your checkbox logic works, why not test it on a simpler case, e.g.:

```
if (movieCost5 == true && movieCost10 == false)
{
   movies = new[] { new Movie { Title = "movieCost5 works correctly" } };
}
else if (movieCost5 == true && movieCost10 == true)
{
   movies = new[] { new Movie { Title = "YAY! Both work as well!" } };
}
else if (movieCost5 == false && movieCost10 == true)
{
   movies = new[] { new Movie { Title = "movieCost10 works correctly" } };
}
```

Comment: Thank you, works when sorting on two or three properties.  Is there a better way to do this, say if I was sorting on numerous properties?  Even with my lack of experience I can't help but think there is a better way.

Comment: One way to do multiple sorts using Linq to SQL would be to have a default sort on your queryable object, even if it's just the database ID: `movies = db.Movies.OrderBy(x => x.Id).AsQueryable()`. Then you can add more sorts to it in a fashion similar to what you have for the prices but instead of a `.Where()` you tack on a `.ThenBy()`. Now, the order these are applied matter so it gets a little more complicated if you want users to apply sorting in the order they're chosen. That would take more space than the comments allow here.